# Java - NetBeans parameters while executing console app

Tags: java, netbeans, parameter-passing

I am developing console Java app which needs to accept parametres when executing. I am developing in NetBeans, how to add parametres there while I am debugging?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very simple. Right-click your project and choose Properties. The Run Category will allow you to set the Arguments. 'foo' is the argument here...

[image: foo is your argument]

Answer (score 2):

The answer is here: http://netbeanside61.blogspot.com/2009/02/using-command-line-arguments-in.html